# Impulse response function single coil

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, coil, electromagnetic

How can I measure the impulse response function of a single coil - like an electromagnetic shaker?

The construction of a second winding would be difficult. I was thinking about a T/R switch but there will be better ideas - I hope...

[image: Electromagnetic shaker]

<sub>Image source: [Schematic view of an electromagnetic shaker](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-view-of-an-electromagnetic-shaker_fig2_228893822)</sub>

Comment: Draw an equivalent circuit.

Comment: A second winding would change your inductor into a transformer. In that case the load on the additional port will change the impulse response, and it has to be taken into account when deriving the equivalent circuit model from the measurement.

Comment: How are you defining the input and output signals? Also, the system doesn’t appear to be time invariant.

Comment: @Chu As the target is movable I expect a 'response' (in form of a certain current) from the system.

Comment: How do you intend to generate the stimulus pulse with infinite height and zero width?

Answer (score 2):

Consider all of the variables in play with a shaker like the one you have shown.

The inductance of the coil varies depending on the position of the "target."  As the target moves closer to the "electromagnet" the inductance will increase.  This is true when the target is not moving, but when it is moving, the energized, magnetized coil generates its own voltage, similar to the back emf of a motor.  How quickly the target is moving depends both on the mass of the target, which must be accelerated by the "resultant force,"(F=MA) after subtracting the force of the spring that is part of the shaker to provide return to the start position when the current is removed.  The spring rate determines the instantaneous spring force, which is dependent on its position and preload.  The resultant force is not constant for a given current, but changes in a non-linear fashion depending on the distance between the electromagnet and the target.  When you finally add in the non-linearity of the core material, you can see that the response of the device must be dependent on a large number of initial conditions: notably target mass, position, spring force, and the amplitude of the input.  The system does not lend itself to the calculation of an impulse response that will be useful over a range of conditions and input amplitudes.

You could measure a step or sine response for a given mass and input amplitude from a static position using an accelerometer on the target mass, and create a table of responses for different masses at different input amplitudes.  This at least would give you a feel for the range of inputs for a given mass where the shaker response was somewhat proportional to the input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm aware that I will get the whole system with non-linear effects - but this is what I really want! You described more or less my view of the problem.
As you state in the last passage the obvious measurement would be the usage of an accelerometer. But my idea is to measure the back emf (in a static position using a step) to see if any parameters could be determined. But I still don't know how...